# Grails vs Spring

Tags: java, spring, grails, database-performance

Can any one please explain me that whats the better option for an enterprise java web application of more than 500 database tables.Either we should use Grails or Go for (Spring,hibernate and Spring MVC/Struts 2).If you suggest grails then please elaborate why not the other one and if Spring then why not grails.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that Grails is actually a layer on top of Spring MVC. I recommend strongly against Struts for any new project; Thymeleaf is generally a better option if you're going for Spring MVC, or possibly the Groovy markup language if you're using Grails.

Comment: @chrylis thankyou for your response.I found groovy markup language more easier than Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was in the same situation about 4 month ago, and I wasn't familiar with Grails, but I want to have a platform to develop our website very fast and I think our project is as big as yours, we started to work with spring and start using spring roo for mvc but as time goes by we find out that spring will not satisfy our need, and roo is not what we want so we switch to Grails and I found Grails one of the best web frameworks that I ever worked with. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653618/scaffolding-for-spring-mvc-portlet) is one of the question that was in my mind about spring roo.

All in all as a satisfied customer of Grails, strongly suggest Grails.

(In my opinion, Grails and AngularJs are the prefect match.)

Comment: sorry i was away for last couple of days thats why replying late here.Yes you are right,we also decided to go for Grails becasue its fast,reliable and need nothing to configure which is the best thing about grails.

Comment: @umairyasin thanks I think you make a good choice:)

Comment: So you use groovy on grails or something else? @ali-amiri and umair-yasin ?

Comment: @tgkprog I used grails on groovy if that is what you mean, but what elese is there?

Comment: I was not sure, have used grovy in a stand tool / just scripts for testing (soapui). I have heard of GOG, but only used spring mvc. So wondering if there was something else :) Thank you. @ali-amiri. So with GOG are you able to solve all your problems with pure GOG or do you need to add java code (spring beans etc)?

Comment: @tgkprog not every projects are the same, but I solve I my problems with grails :)

Comment: How **Grails** is a **programming language**?

Comment: @Benedictus I really dont understand what you are saying, you say grail is not a real programming language?!

Comment: @Lrrr what do you mean "real programming language" it has nothing to do with programming language at all, it's a framework. But I guess you're referring to groovy. Anyway, you made my day, sir.

Comment: @Benedictus yes I'm referring to groovy and it is very common to say grails instead of grails on groovy exactly like ruby!

Comment: looks like your "here" link is not available. Could you please check?

Comment: @AidenZhao that link is not that important, it is just an old question that I've asked(without any answers) to show the OP that I have the same problem(but I've deleted my question)