# Which framework should I use (Grails, Java/Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, grails

I would like to create the back-end framework for my website using one of the following: Groovy Grails or Java.

My main concern is scalability/performance and the app will  be able to handle large sets of data, primarily read heavy.

I will be using HTML5/JavaScript/Jquery for the front end and MySql but not hibernate spring JdbcTemplate

Any info would be greatly appreciated, I am fluent with Java and Spring and have made a few small apps with Groovy/Grails.

Edit: Some more specifications: I have to use java mails

Comment: This type of question (asking for a recommendation for a framework) is off-topic on StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and also read [ask].

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic, voted to close. Grails is awesome if you are comfortable with Hibernate, people not familiar with Hibernate tend to get confused.

Comment: This might help you out [Grails vs Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073253/grails-vs-spring)

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest you to go with Groovy Grails. Simple reason, which you might be aware of as you have developed Grails application, is that Grails follow Convention over Configuration which simply means less configuration (unlike Spring and Hibernate), less time, less work and more output.

Keep in mind  Grails under the hood is SPRING and HIBERNATE. So whenever you write a GORM query it would be better and optimised than writing everything yourself. Expect it to be highly scalable with very good performance if you follow the best ways for your DB calls. In any case it would be very easy to write and in the long run the Grails stuff will be much more maintainable as well.

Regarding front end, you are free to use HTML5/JavaScript/jQuery in a GSP page with lots of helpful Taglibs prebuilt for you. You might design one Taglib if needed. On the other hand even if you wish may be now or later, you can even use front end frameworks like AngularJS along with RESTful services on your server.

Regarding Java mails, you can use it or any other library in Grails which you have in Java.

Regarding your fluency with Java and Spring, it is going to take some days to be fluent in Grails but once done then in next few days you will make up any lost ground.

Comment: one plus for your time

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I am digressing a bit, I have been a great fan of Servlet's and Spring's of the world (not much of groovy/grails), but recently did a POC on a product idea and used Play/Scala (or java) combo to greatest benefits and to summarize it -

**Play! keeps you on the right track, forcing you to carefully consider your memory usage, which produces first-pass code that is practically cluster ready.**

So, essentially, with Play/Scala scalability/throughput is not an afterthought rather built into the way we program on it. Hope it helps.

Comment: one plus for trying.. @avish